# Change row value to column in SQL

Tags: sql, pivot

I have table in sql  i want to change fieldColumnName as a column and fieldValue as a row.
this is my table image

[image: Table Image]

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Since you tagged it with `pivot`, you know the technical name of what you want to do. So I assume you searched online for how to do it, but couldn't get it to work. Can you show us what you tried?

Comment: google how to create ascii tables and show your table data in ascii table format. Also show your expected output

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name SQL

Comment: SQL is a query language used by all relational databases. It's not a DBMS product.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, You want to alter table (change column name as well as data type)

```
ALTER TABLE tablename   
  CHANGE `fieldColumnName` `column` VARCHAR(255),
  CHANGE `fieldValue` `row` VARCHAR(255)
```

In above query you change datatype as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

If you know all the possible values in the fieldColumnName column then you could use pivot like this:

```
declare @data table(fieldValue varchar(50), fieldColumnName varchar(50))

INSERT INTO @data
SELECT '1 - value', 'col1'
UNION
SELECT '2 - value', 'col2'
UNION
SELECT NULL, 'col6'

select * 
from @data

select col1, col2, col3
from
(
  select fieldValue, fieldColumnName
  from @data
) d
pivot
(
  max(fieldValue)
  for fieldColumnName in (col1, col2, col3)
) piv;
```